# Is it possible to programmatically cancel a non-auto-renewing subscription before finishTransaction and after SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase

If two devices pay for the same non-auto-renewing subscription signed in to the same account (not the same itunes account, but the same account on our developer server).  Then what would happen...

- Is it possible to programmatically cancel the payment for the 2nd device, or is it too late by the time iTunes gives the receipt?
- If the devices were signed into the same developer account *and* the same iTunes account.  Would iTunes stop the user from buying the same subscription?
- What else can be done to prevent this from occurring (other than to sync up with the developer server before initiating a purchase).
  [image]